# Custom UITableViewCell objects being released - prototype cells in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios5, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and a table view controller which I want to insert text boxes into.

What I have done is setup a three dimensional array to store the sections, rows and then in the third dimension I have put the placeholder text I would like to display -

In the custom UITableViewCell subclass I have defined the text box as a weak property (I think this is correct...?)

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField *plainTextField;
```

I then add this text field to my data model array in

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

however, when I try to access the textfield from my array (specifically plainTextField.text) I get

```
''
```

I get the feeling that something is being released somewhere and I can't figure out where (the actual textfield is not nil)

I guess, my question is really a design one -- how do you get UITextFields into a UITableViewController and then get the text out of them later....?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've 'fixed' my problem -- it's really based on the fact that you can't have different content in UITableViewCells, as soon as anything is different you have to load it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. (A note in the UITableViewCell prepareForReuse method)

What I did was reserve a spot in my data model for a UITextField, and then when cellForRowAtIndex path got to the cell it would query the data model, then instantiate a UITextField and add it to the `cell.contentView` or (here's the tricky part) *loop through `[cell.contentview subviews]` to find any UITextFields and call `removeFromSuperview`*